# Drag and Drop using Javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, drag-and-drop

I want to have a if condition.
After the drop is performed if the condition is not satisfied then the dropped item should revert back to its original position.
I want to do it in javascript

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  if(ev.target.id=="div2"){
  alert(data+" "+ev.target.id);
  }
  else{

  I want the revert to happen here
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>

</body>
```

Can somebody please help me?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write drop code inside your if condition so if condion is not satisfied the item will not been dropped in the div check below i have edited your code

```
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:red;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:blue;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:orange;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:wheat;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();

if(ev.target.id=="div2"){
alert(data+" "+ev.target.id);
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can drop the image into **`div2`**. After that, if you try to drag the image from **`div2`** and place it to another **`div(here div3 and div4)`** it will be placed to its original div which is **`div1`**. I think that's what you wanted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #div1,
        #div2,
        #div3,
        #div4 {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 35px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

            if (ev.target.id === "div2") {
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }
            else {

                // I want the revert to happen here
                document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
    <p>Drag the image back and forth between the two div elements.</p>

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img src="img_w3slogo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
    </div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>

</html>
```